# MongoDB commands in linux console with --eval (print

Tags: arrays, mongodb, shell, command, eval

I try run command mongo in linux console without entering into mongo shell.
To do it:

> [root@router-mongos ~]# mongo --eval " printjson(show databases)"

But not run, this is the output:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
>   connecting to: test
>   2015-06-10T18:33:39.834+0200 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Though if you are uses:

> [root@router-mongos ~]# mongo maria --eval " printjson (db.stats())"
>   o
>   mongo --eval " printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))"

Yes, the output is the same if you run it in shell.

Has anyone ever used this? can we help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Mongo Shell documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo):

> You **cannot** use any shell helper (e.g. `use <dbname>`, `show dbs`, etc.) inside the JavaScript file because they are not valid JavaScript.

Following that, there is a table showing the JavaScript equivalents of the various [shell helpers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers). From that, `show dbs` and `show databases` should be replaced by `db.adminCommand('listDatabases')` in your Mongo shell scripts.